# Pseudocode: Recursively process start/stop times in list

Tags: algorithm, recursion, profiling, pseudocode

Here's rather nebulous question.

I have a list of start/stop times from script executions, which may include nested script calls.

```
| script | start | stop |    duration    |            time executing           |
| ------ | ----- | ---- | -------------- | ----------------------------------- |
| A      |     1 |    8 | 7 i.e. (8-1)   | 3 i.e. ((8-1) - (6-2) - (5-4))      |
| ->B    |     2 |    6 | 4 i.e. (6-2)   | 3 i.e. ((6-2) - (5-4))              |
| ->->C  |     4 |    5 | 1 i.e. (5-4)   | 1                                   |
| D      |     9 |   10 | 1 i.e. (10-9)  | 1                                   |
| E      |    11 |   12 | 1 i.e. (12-11) | 1                                   |
| F      |     9 |   16 | 7 i.e. (16-9)  | 5 i.e. ((16-9) - (14-13) - (16-15)) |
| ->G    |    13 |   14 | 4 i.e. (14-13) | 1 i.e. (14-13)                      |
| ->H    |    15 |   16 | 1 i.e. (15-14) | 1 i.e. (16-15)                      |
```

Duration is the total time spent in a script.
Time executing is the time spent in the script, but not in subscript.

So A calls B and B calls C. C takes 1 tick, B takes 4 but time executing is just 3, and A takes 7 ticks, but time executing is 3.
F calls G and then H, so takes 7 ticks but time executing is only 5.

What I'm trying to wrap my ('flu-ridden) head around is a pseudo-code algorithm for step-wise or recursing through the list of times in order to generate the time executing value for each row.

Any help for this problem (or cure for common cold) gratefully received. :-)

Comment: Actually they are, if the omission apostrophe is for Man-influenza

Comment: Is it possible to have a scenario where A-->B A-->C ||||| B-->D ||||| C-->E , where B and C are immediate sub scripts of script A, D is subscript of B and E is subscript of C?  A DFS starting at each root node should give you the execution time of each row along with its childern. The open question I have is how do you identify the root node and weather a subscript is child i.e. a left child or right child.

Comment: Purely from the times. That is the point.

Comment: OK, so you don't know *and* don't care which script ran which script?  (You can infer this info from the start and stop times, but you can only do so perfectly if all start and stop times are distinct -- which would be my next question: Are they?)

Comment: Yep. Distinct. Actually, the table above is a simplification - there is an ip address and a user & process id in there too. But basically, distinct.

Comment: I have now managed to cobble something together - I will reverse-engineer the solution to pseudo code this evening, after work. I appreciate everyone looking into it.

Comment: NB: Cure for man-'flu still outstanding issue ;-)

Comment: I just posted a solution, which is probably the same as the one you came up with, but anyway... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all time points are distinct, then script execution timespans are related to each other by an ordered tree: Given any pair of script execution timespans, either one strictly contains the other, or they don't overlap at all.  This enables an easy recovery of parent-child relationships, if you wanted to do that.

But if you just care about execution times, we don't even need that!  :)  There's a pretty simple algorithm that just sorts the starting and ending times and walks through the resulting array of "events", maintaining a stack of open "frames":

1. Create an array of `(time, scriptID)` pairs, and insert the start time and end time of each script into it (i.e., insert two pairs per script into the same array).
2. Sort the array by time.
3. Create a stack of integer triples, and push a single `(0, 0, 0)` entry on it.  (This is just a dummy entry to simplify later code.)  Also create an array `seen[]` with a boolean flag per script ID, all initially set to `false`.
4. Iterate through the sorted array of `(time, scriptID)` pairs:

   - Whenever you see a `(time, scriptID)` pair for a script ID that you have not seen before, that script is starting.

     - Set `seen[scriptID] = true`.
     - Push the triple `(time, scriptID, 0)` onto the stack.  The final component, initially 0, will be used to accumulate the total duration spent in this script's "descendant" scripts.
   - Whenever you see a time for a script ID that you have seen before (because `seen[scriptID] == true`), that script is ending.

     - Pop the top `(time, scriptID, descendantDuration)` triple from the stack (note that the scriptID in this triple should match the scriptID in the pair at the current index of the array; if not, then somehow you have "intersecting" script timespans that could not correspond to any sequence of nested script runs).
     - The duration for this script ID is (as you already knew) `time - startTime[scriptID]`.
     - Its execution time is `duration - descendantDuration`.
     - Record the time spent in this script *and its descendants* by adding its `duration` to the new top-of-stack's `descendantDuration` (i.e., third) field.

That's all!  For n script executions this will take O(n log n) time, because the sorting step takes that long (iterating over the array and performing the stack operations take just O(n)).  Space usage is O(n).

Comment: Thank you j_random_hacker - that is almost what I'm using - but because the values are in a db table I can get at some of them without a stack. However, you get the points for being so kind as to provide a solution. I appreciate it.

Comment: Half a bottle of Amaretto before bed, is the current favourite solution for that, according to a Clinical Biologist colleague...